# Recorrer Arrays con PHP

Tags: php

Realizo una consulta via API y como respuesta obtengo un `JSON` el cual almaceno en una variable y lo convierto en un Array:

```
$items = json_decode( $access__resultado, true );
```

Imprimo una parte del Array (la que me interesa) de la siguiente forma:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $items["accesses"] );
echo "</pre>";
```

Y me da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [access_id] => 8o5THPq8mofa
    )
    
    [1] => Array (
        [access_id] => mmBAHc107Unp
    )
    
    [2] => Array (
        [access_id] => gDDOyPQIXH60
    )
)
```

¿Como puedo recorrerlo para obtener el valor de cada `access_id`? He intentado de las siguientes formas, pero no me muestra nada:

```
$accesses = $items["accesses"]; // Opción 1
$accesses = $items->accesses; // Opción 2
foreach ( $accesses as $val ) {
    echo $value["access_id"]; // Opción 1
    echo $value->access_id; // Opción 2
}
```

Comment: En el `foreach` tienes `$val` y en el `echo` tienes `$value`..

Comment: Esta opción: **`$value["access_id"];`** es la correcta siempre y cuando uses `$val` que es la clave que te recupera cada valor en las iteraciones, la otra no es válida por que no estas recuperando un objeto si no un array de arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el bucle foreach, el primer elemento $accesses es el sub-arrsy que quieres recorrer. En el lado derecho del 'as'  defines la variable $val, que va a ser cada elemento. En este caso cada $val contiene una clave access_id.

Por lo tanto, dentro de tu bucle debes acceder a $val y no a $value, que no lo tienes definido en tu ejemplo. Pon dentro de tu bucle:

```
echo $val['access_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás mostrando un valor incorrecto; la función foreach evidentemente te permite recorrer el array pero en tu código al declarar estás dándole un valor al ítem, el cual no estás llamando.

```
$accesses = $items["accesses"]; // Opción 1
$accesses = $items->accesses; // Opción 2
foreach ( $accesses as $val ) {
    echo $value["access_id"]; // Opción 1
    echo $value->access_id; // Opción 2
}
```

Lo correcto sería

```
echo $val["access_id"]; // Opción 1
```